# HTML: make a splash image have a relative clickable area

Tags: html, css, image

I have a splash page for my website that is implemented as a background image on a main div:

```
#main
{
    background:url('../img/splash.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
    margin:auto;
}

...
<body>
     <div id="main">
     ...
     </ div>
</body>
...
```

Issue is that I want to make a part of the backround image clickable into our website. I've implmented this by setting a transparent box around the area I want clickable using position:absolute:

```
#logo-link 
{ 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 30px; 
        left: 350px; 
        width: 600px; 
        height: 280px; 
        background-color: transparent; 
}

...
<div>
    <a id="logo-link" href="/mylink"></a>
</div>
...
```

This works when I set the box on my screen, but I've noticed that the box shifts around on other screen resolutions. To the point where a screen with a much higher resolution has the box shifted to block out a form field to signup on my site!

I believe I've implemented the clickable area of a splash page poorly, can you show me how to do better?

Thanks.

Comment: Add `position: relative` to the properties for the selector `#main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***[Live demo][1]***](http://tinkerbin.com/O3yFKLTl)...................................
Hi now define `**#main**` `position:relative;`

as like this

```
#main{
position:relative;
}
```

[***[Live demo][2]***](http://tinkerbin.com/O3yFKLTl)